# .net core 2.1 lambda using a custom root CA

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

I need to connect to a remote service from a .net 2.1 AWS lambda and the remote service is secured with https and a custom certificate generated by a private certificate authority.

How do I make the lambda trust the certificate without globally disabling all remote validation checks?